# Open downloaded epub files in WebView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, epub, win-universal-app

I google a lot over this and still can't found a way to make it work

My app downloads epubs from many sources and then I save them to the local Storage (and unzip them)

I can read the extracted files with no problems with Storage commands but just can't to open it on  WebView control

I tried all this:

The real path: C:\Data\Users\DefApps\APPDATA\Local\Packages\xxx\LocalState\***

```
Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///***/OEBPS/04_CL_CH.01.xhtml");
Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///***/OEBPS/04_CL_CH.01.xhtml");
Uri localUri = new Uri("file:///***/OEBPS/04_CL_CH.01.xhtml");
Uri localUri = new Uri("file:///LocalState/***/OEBPS/04_CL_CH.01.xhtml");
Uri localUri = new Uri("file:///C://Data//Users//DefApps//APPDATA//Local//Packages//xxx//LocalState//***//OEBPS//04_CL_CH.01.xhtml");

// two ways

WebView1.Navigate(localUri);
WebView1.Source = localUri;

// this works, but as is an epub file, so need lot of files and styles

var XHTML = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("***\\OEBPS\\04_CL_CH.01.xhtml");

WebView1.NavigateToString(await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(XHTML));
```

This is a C# Windows Phone universal app, and I'm using VS 2013 Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/07/17/whats-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1/, it says:

> ms-appdata:///local/TopLevelDirectory/file for files from the local
>   state
>
> ms-appdata:///temp/TopLevelDirectory/file for files from the
>   app’s temporary state folder

Comment: Will try at home in 2 hours. I have tried before (as my question mention) but without "local" word